# How to set pure red pixel full screen on iPhone OLED

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am studying the pixel arrangement of the iPhone OLED screen.
I use the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        data[(i*width + j)*4] = (Byte) (255) ;
        data[(i*width + j)*4+1] = (Byte) (0) ;     
        data[(i*width + j)*4+2] = (Byte) (0) ;  
        data[(i*width + j)*4+3] = (Byte)255;
    }
 }
```

in the viewController, when setting the iPhone X full screen to red, the screen pixels of the iPhone X seen with the microscope is not all red pixels, and green pixels can also be seen first.

What I want to achieve is that when setting to pure red, the pixels of the iPhone X only display red pixels, and green pixels or blue pixels cannot be displayed.
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Does this also happen when you disable True Tone and Night Shift?

Comment: ths guys.It is also existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with system color:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
```

iOS offers a range of system colors that automatically adapt to vibrancy and changes in accessibility settings like Increase Contrast and Reduce Transparency.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/

Comment: Ths guys,I use UIColor.systemRed code ,but the pixel arrangement also contain green pixel

Comment: @wjiushiwya if you try a solution, please write me... now I'm curious :)

Comment: The Information above can not solved my issue I method...May I ask what is the "Please write me" meaning for?

Comment: @wjiushiwya I'm just curious, if I were to have the same problem, you would help me to solve it...

Comment: I find the solution,the function as belowe can solve the issue

 + (UIColor *)colorWithDisplayP3Red:(CGFloat)displayP3Red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha